# Cocoa - Determining a class' properties at run time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

Is this simple?  I'm actually trying to monitor if an object changes (to determine if I should save it).  Currently I just have an array in the object with a list of all of it's readwrite properties, then I loop through it after the object is created and add observers:

```
for ( NSString *observer in _observers ){
    [self addObserver: self forKeyPath: observer options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context: nil];
}
```

It works, but if you forget to add a property to the array, obviously the observer won't be called.  Does anyone know how I can just determine the object's properties at runtime?  I was thinking it may be around respondsToSelector: but I haven't been able to find much on the subject.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A better way to do this would be a `hasChanged` dependent key: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002179-BAJEAIEE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Properties of an object, after they have been synthesized, behave almost like ordinary object's methods, so you can do following check

```
if ([myObject respondsToSelector: @selector(propertyName)]) {
    // your code here
}
```

Or if you want to use strings as selector's name:

```
if ([myObject respondsToSelector: NSSelectorFromString(@"propertyName")]) {
    // your code here
}
```

Here `propertyName` is a getter (it's signature name exactly corresponds to your declared property name), so if you want to check for setter presence, you should add additional expression:

```
[myObject respondsToSelector: @selector(setPropertyName:)])
```

Comment: `NSSelectorFromString()` gives you a selector without needing `@selector()`

Answer (score 3):

May be this will help:

You can get list of properties in a class using `class_copyPropertyList`

```
objc_property_t * class_copyPropertyList(Class cls, unsigned int *outCount)
```

and then from each property you can get its name using `property_getName` function and attributes using property_getAttributes function (if you need to filter read-write properties).

For more details see [Objective-c Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: +1, although this only copies the properties declared on `cls`, and *not* any declared on superclasses.

Comment: It also won't work for `@property` declarations that don't have a KVO compliant implementation.  And it won't work for setter/getter methods that are declared in the traditional fashion (think -frame and -setFrame:).  All in all, you *could* do something like this, but down this path lies madness;  you really don't want this kind of automatic all-encompassing behavior in your infrastructure.

Comment: @bbum what is the best method to achieve what I'm looking for?  Hash all my objects + check for changes?